# Multidimensional array from simple list

Tags: php, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array

I have a function which works like this and it draws  dropdown menu.

```
$options = array(
array('--- Select option ---'),
array('option1'),
array('option2'),
);

return array(
        'title' => $this->name,
        'options' => array(
            array(
                'id' => 'option_1',
                'name' => '',
                'fields' => functions::form_draw_select_field('adresiukas', $options, true) ,
            ),
        ),
    );
```

What I would like to do instead is take options from csv like this:

```
$options = functions::csv_decode($this->settings['my_options'], ';');
```

where options list looks like this:

```
option1;
option2;
option3;
...
option15;
```

How to put these as multidimensional array correctly to be able to use options from csv? Now it only shows blank lines for options without any text.

Here's a result of csv_decode funtion using print_r:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [name] => option1 [] => ) 
[1] => Array ( [name] => option2 [] => ) 
[2] => Array ( [name] => option3 [] => ) )
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [name] => option1 [] => ) 
[1] => Array ( [name] => option2 [] => ) 
[2] => Array ( [name] => option3 [] => ) )
```

My options are saved as textfield in such format:

```
name;
option1;
option2;
option3;
```

Comment: well you need to start somewhere, you'll need to use the function that opens files in php

Comment: Can you show what the result of `functions::csv_decode()` call is.

Comment: added resutt to the first post